# Dependency Walker on .NET applications: FlsAlloc

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dependency-walker

I have tried to profile several .NET executables in dependency walker and always get something like this:

GetProcAddress(0x7C800000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsAlloc") called from "MSCOREE.DLL" at address 0x79006079 and returned 0xFFBADD11.

I tried making a new windows forms project VS2005 and did nothing but build it.  Dependency walker still gives that same error.  Does this mean that it is no longer possible to profile .Net applications, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependency walker can only profile unmanaged programs.

Comment: Okay I can accept that :), any idea on a better way to track issues with managed dlls?

Comment: I was referring to depedency problems, such as modules not being loaded and dlls not being found.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, but the FAQ says this:

Will Dependency Walker work with COM, Visual Basic, or .NET modules?

Yes. Dependency Walker will work with any 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module, regardless of what language was used to develop it.  However, many languages have their own way to specify dependency relationships between modules.  For example, COM modules may have embedded type libraries and registration information in the registry, and .NET modules may use .NET assemblies.  These techniques are all implemented as layers above the core Windows API.  In the end, these layers still need to call down to the core Windows functions like LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to do the actual work.  It is at this core level that Dependency Walker understands what is going on.  So, while Dependency Walker may not understand all the language specific complexities of your application, it will still be able to track all module activity at a core Windows API level.